# Can i set a custom tag and a custom value in laravel component?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-components

```
<div class="bg-white dark:bg-custom-black-600 dark:text-white rounded px-4 pb-4 pt-2">
    <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex justify-between items-center">
        <h4 class="font-semibold flex-shrink-0">
            {{ __('services') }}
        </h4>
        <i class="ri-hard-drive-2-fill text-blue-600 dark:text-blue-600"></i>
    </div>
    <p class="text-3xl text-blue-600">
        {{ Auth::user()->services->count() }}
    </p>
</div>
```

this is my code from the component `card.blade.php`. Now the question: "Can I make a custom value that I have to specify in the tag `<x-card title="" service="">` or is that not possible? I would like `{{ __('services') }}` and  `{{ Auth::user()->services->count() }}` not to be static in the code example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write a component class to handle variables in the template. That class would interpret the input and store it in variables that can be accessed in the template. This is all described [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#passing-data-to-components).

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Card extends Component
{
    public function __construct(
        public string $title,
        public string $service,
    )
    {}

    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.card');
    }
}
```

Call the component like this:

```html
<x-card title="Something" service="something else"/>
```

And you should then be able to use `$title` and `$service` in the Blade template file. Note if you want to use PHP values, you'll need to do something like this:

```html
<x-card :title="__('something')" service="something else"/>
```

Note the colon preceding the attribute name.